# How to remove x-powered-by header in .net core 2.0

Tags: c#, azure, security

I tried to use this middleware:

```
public class SecurityHeadersMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate next;

    public SecurityHeadersMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this.next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var ctx = (HttpContext)state;

            if (!ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity"))
            {
                ctx.Response.Headers.Add("Arr-Disable-Session-Affinity", "True"); // Disables the Azure ARRAffinity cookie
            }

            if (ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("Server"))
            {
                ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("Server"); // For security reasons
            }

            if (ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("x-powered-by") || ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Powered-By"))
            {
                ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("x-powered-by");
                ctx.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
            }

            if (!ctx.Response.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Frame-Options"))
            {
                ctx.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "DENY");
            }

            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }, context);

        await next(context);
    }
}
```

x-powered-by is still there in response header which says asp.net

Answer (score 31, accepted):

- In addition to @Brando Zhang answer, To remove "Server:Kestrel" from response header:

-.NET Core 1

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();
```

-NET Core 2

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
               .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
               .UseStartup<Startup>()
               .Build();
```

Comment: This goes in the project's Program.cs file, you should see an existing entry but without the .UseKestrel() call

Comment: this don´t remove the x-powered-by header!

Comment: @BerBar It does if you're not running the application in IIS... E.G. run it as a console app

Comment: Remove the x-powered-by using IIS manager, http headers. Just delete them out of the list.

Comment: ".UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)" only removes the "Server" header.  It has no impact on X-Powered-By

Comment: I have head to remove the header in IIS on the server as this configures that as well

Answer (score 50):

As far as I know, the removal of these headers is facilitated with the Request Filtering module, which is part of IIS.

To remove a header, you need to have a web.config file stored on your site, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>


</configuration>
```

Add this web.config to your net core application's root folder.

Then it will remove the x-powered-by header.

The result like this:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only way to do this since the header is generated by IIS. There's some further information including comments by the .Net Core Hosting team here: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/571

Comment: How about removing `Server: Kestrel`?

Comment: @flipdoubt check this SO answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452194/remove-server-header-from-asp-net-core-2-1-application

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to create a web.config file in a ASP.NET Core solution, you can remove the `X-Powered-By` header in IIS Manager.

Click on `<ServerName> --> HTTP Response Headers --> X-Powered-By` and choose the `Remove` action.

[image: IIS]

This will remove the header for all websites on that server. Which is fine because why would you want to share that info in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative option to the answers above you can use a [*configuration transformation*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/transform-webconfig). That way the `web.config` will still be generated via the dotnet publisher sdk but can be mixed with specific tags such as the header removal.

In the root of the project create a new `web.Release.config` file as such:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
  <location>

    <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
    For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <customHeaders>
          <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>

  </location>
</configuration>
```

Note that this is a *transformation file*, not the actual `web.config` file.