# Remove "Server" header from ASP.NET Core 2.1 application

Tags: asp.net-core, web-config, asp.net-core-2.1, kestrel-http-server

Is it possible to remove the **Server** Response header in a ASP.NET Core 2.1 application (running on Server 2016 with IIS 10)?

I tried putting the following in the web.config:

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
            <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
            <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
            <remove name="Server" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
</system.webServer>
```

The first four alterations to the Response worked fine, but the **Server** header was not removed.  I still see "Kestrel"

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The Kestrel Server header gets added too late in the request pipeline. Therefore removing it via the web.config or via middleware is not possible.

You can remove the Server header by setting the [AddServerHeader property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserveroptions.addserverheader?view=aspnetcore-2.1) to `false` on `KestrelServerOptions`, this can be done in the Program.cs.

```cs
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Comment: This does not removes the header. kestrel gives response to IIS and iis adds this header. To remove this header you have to configure web.config file

Comment: You have to do all things to remove this header. This setting stops it being set, but kestrel is not the only place which wants hackers to know what tech your server is running. Cover the web config as well (as per the next answer) and you're golden.

Comment: This works if you don't use IIS.

Answer (score 88):

This solution works on IIS 10+ version and allows to remove `x-powered-by` and `server` headers in server response.

In IIS 10 a new attribute was added: `removeServerHeader`.

We need to create `web.config` file in asp.net core application with following content:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Then publish app and restart site on IIS.

Comment: good catch. I spent several hourse trying to remove IIS's Server header. I'll try your solution too.

Comment: Visual Studio complains that the `removeServerHeader` attribute is not allowed.

Comment: @hvaughan3 I noticed that too - Visual Studio does say "the 'removeServerHeader' attribute is not allowed", emphasized by highlighting it with the wobbly green line, but it does work as suggested.  Thanks @user3172616!

Comment: Can I write something in my code to automatically generate this in web.config on publish time?

Comment: This is works for me, my api hosted to IIS 10 and it removed the "Server" header.

Comment: Is there a way to make an earlier version of IIS ignore this attribute? This `removeServerHeader` attribute makes web apps unable to start in IIS 8 :(

Comment: since .net core is not using web.config anymore. are there other alternative to remove server header in iis?

Comment: @ajgo .net core does not include it in the solution files, but when you publish the project it will be included in the published directory. Furthermore it is present in the IIS server directory and can be modified directly or using IIS GUI.

Comment: @HamidSiaban - Thank you for the reply.I just cleared this problem in my side. I fixed it with the help of the web.config file that I manually added in my project. Since our app is running in IIS, I can remove the server header using it

Comment: Works good in Netcore 3.1

Comment: The solution worked perfectly for web pages.. I still see headers coming up on static files which were served. any suggestions for getting rid of it there?

Answer (score 23):

In NET6, it becomes

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(option => option.AddServerHeader = false);
```

Answer (score 9):

For the ones that are trying to do the same thing (removing the Server response header added by Kestrel web server) but using instead ASP.NET core 2.2, they should use the extension method **ConfigureKestrel** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.webhostbuilderkestrelextensions.configurekestrel?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_WebHostBuilderKestrelExtensions_ConfigureKestrel_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Hosting_IWebHostBuilder_System_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServerOptions__) instead of the extension method UseKestrel.

Comment: Hmm, `ConfigureKestrel(x => x.AddServerHeader = false)` has no effect for me. Header is still in place

Comment: @user3172616 are you running the app from Visual Studio or from a test environment having its own server ?

Comment: App is running on remote production server IIS10 (not Kestrel). Anyway i found another solution and posted in this thread.

Comment: @user3172616 Notice that the configuration for Kestrel affects ONLY the HTTP response headers set by kestrel itself. Usually, when you run an ASP.NET core application you use a reverse proxy server sitting in front of your application. This means that the reverse proxy has a chance to add ITS own response headers. For instance, if you use IIS (even IIS express) you will find the Server header added by IIS

Comment: @user3172616 In the case I mentioned above you have to configure the reverse proxy server put in front of the asp.net core application in order to strip its own Server header. The extension method `ConfigureKestrel(x => x.AddServerHeader = false)` only affects Kestrel's headers

Comment: I misunderstood your post answer, sorry. Indeed, that headers are set on IIS level, so i used web.config file to configure this behavior.

Answer (score 8):

For Dotnet Core 3.1 `UseKestrel` is part of `ConfigureWebHostDefaults` as opposed to `CreateDefaultBuilder` in earlier versions.

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>()
                      .UseKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false);
        });
```

Comment: This works. It may be worth mentioning that, if you use this fix, you can't run the application using IISExpress in Visual Studio. You'll get this error: `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Application is running inside IIS process but is not configured to use IIS server.'`

Comment: Same happened to me. `UseKestrel` will failed to run your application in IIS server

Comment: Is there any way we could remove the "Content-Length" header that is added by Kestrel ?

Answer (score 5):

These directions apply to IIS 10.0 only.

1. Open the web.config file located in the root directory for the website.
2. Configure requestFiltering in the web.config system.webServer node:

   ```
   <security>
       <requestFiltering removeServerHeader ="true" />
   </security>
   ```
3. Save the file and restart your IIS app.

Comment: What is the Orion website?

Comment: Sorry, not "Orion" - just "website"

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @SamAlekseev is really good for removing `Server` and `X-Powered-By` header. The only thing missing is removing `X-AspNet-Version` as well. This works for `Azure App Services` as well as `IIS`.

Complete `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
  For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
  <!--
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" />
  </system.webServer>
  -->
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Source:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/