# How to remove 'Server' header from .net core 3.1 api response?

Tags: asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

How to configure .net core 3.1 application to prevent 'Server' in the response header

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452194/remove-server-header-from-asp-net-core-2-1-application

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add a `web.config` file to the web project with this content (you may have additional content you merge in to your `web.config` file):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true" />
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It doesn't remove server in my application.

Answer (score 11):

If you want to remove the "Kestrel" value returned as Server header, then the correct answer to the question is to do this using the KestrelServerOptions.

While it is possible to use web.config, it is more proper to not have the header added by the runtime to begin with.

This is how you turn off the server header in .NET Core 3.1, add the ConfigureKestrel call within your ConfigureWebHostDefaults method in Program.cs:

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
   serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false;
});
```

Here is a full example to set the context where you can add it:

```
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
   }

   public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
         Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
               webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
               {
                  serverOptions.AddServerHeader = false;
               });

               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Comment: I see now that the comment linked by @VillageTech above has the same answer. Sorry about duplicate answer.

Answer (score 9):

In .Net 6 ASP.Net Core

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false);
```