# Remove Server:Kestrel Header in Net Core 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.0

**Question**

How do you remove "Server:Kestrel" from the response header in a .Net Core 3 application?

[image]

In earlier versions you could do something like the below which is mentioned in this Stack Overflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48145746/2468342).

**Net Core 1**

```
 var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

**Net Core 2**

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
           .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
           .UseStartup<Startup>()
           .Build();
```

**Net Core 3** (UseKestrel() is not found, and does not work, so the below is not possible.)

```
 public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel(c => c.AddServerHeader = false)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should still be able to set Kestrel configuration, things have just moved a bit

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .ConfigureKestrel(options => options.AddServerHeader = false)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
```